# Does CoCreateInstance call indicate that w3wp.exe is starting / restarting?

Tags: asp.net, iis, clr

So I see tons of these errors in the Windows Application Log indicating that a CLR profiler (BMC's ApsAgent Probe in my case) is failing to load.

> .NET Runtime version 4.0.30319.18444 - Loading profiler failed during
>   CoCreateInstance.  Profiler CLSID:
>   '{FF51CB90-1C9F-4b50-BA41-D48BDE9823B0}'.  HRESULT: 0x8007045a. 
>   Process ID (decimal): 4176.  Message ID: [0x2504].

I read on [this msdn post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dougste/archive/2009/12/30/failed-to-cocreate-profiler.aspx) that this sort of profiler gets loaded **when the process starts**. So my question is this: Does that mean every time I see this error in the event viewer I can infer that the associated process (w3wp.exe) is starting? Does that also mean my entire web application is restarting? (btw, the application pool is only set to use one process - ie NOT a "web garden").

Comment: Search for FF51CB90-1C9F-4b50-BA41-D48BDE9823B0 id in registry under HKEY_CLASS_ROOT and check that to which dll/assembly/exe it maps to. You will get idea that of what instance is being created.

Comment: My question isn't about the error, but rather does it mean that my process is restarting every time that error shows up..

Comment: If you have access to the server, you could try "external" tools like _Process Monitor_ or _Process Explorer_ from SysInternals to see if and how often a process (w3wp.exe in your case) restarts.

Comment: *"Does CoCreateInstance call indicate that w3wp.exe is starting / restarting?"* - No. It means, that a COM object is being instantiated. This could mean, that a surrogate process gets started. If you are trying to deduce this type of information from circumstantial evidence, you'll find yourself hunting phantom bugs, sooner or later. If you need to know when/how often your web server restarts, have the [Event Viewer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766042.aspx) tell you.